# Insertion sort homework

Tags: c++, sorting

In the input I have to specify the array as well as it's elements and the output should be in the form given below

input

```
5
2 4 6 8 3
```

Sample Output

```
2 4 6 8 8 
2 4 6 6 8 
2 4 4 6 8 
2 3 4 6 8
```

And this is my output

```
2 4 6 8 8
 2 4 6 6 8
 2 4 4 6 8
 2 4 3 6 8
 2 3 3 6 8
 2 3 3 6 8
```

---

```
int main() {    

    int* a=0;
    int n,x;
    std::cout<<"Enter size ";
    std:: cin>>n;
    std::cout<<"Enter elements ";
    a=new int[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        std::cin>>x;
        a[i]=x;
    }

    int q=a[n-1];
    for(int i=n;i>=0;i--){
        if(a[i-2]>q)
        {   a[i-1]=a[i-2];
        }else 
            a[i]=q;

        for(int j=0;j<n;j++ )
        {   std::cout<<a[j];cout<<" ";
        }
        cout<<" \n ";
    }

    //for(int j=0;j<n;j++ ){std::cout<<a[j];}
    getch();             
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Finding out is part of your homework, I'd say ...

Comment: Try pencil and paper. Work through several inputs carefully by hand.

Comment: Yeah so I started from the scratch and used paper and pen and sadly getting formatting issues which I can't iron out.

Comment: And why is my post getting down voted?I have just started programming so the questions might seem a little dumb.

Answer (score 2):

Since `i` goes all the way down to `0`. Then `i-2` can go to `-2`. Thus this line indexes before the beginning of the array, which is undefined behavior:

```
    if(a[i-2]>q)
```

Here you are assigning over the value in the array without remembering what the old value was.

```
    }else 
        a[i]=q;
```

Thus you are loosing information and thus something is going to go wrong as a sort is not supposed to destroy information.